# Export multiple SQL databases to one CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've seen this done before on other websites, but after a few days at this, I can't seem to get it to work.

I have two tables: "projects_2016" and "attachment".

I would like to export the data into one single CSV file. So far I am able to export only "projects_2016" data no problem. However I would like to have a single row of data from "projects_2016" be displayed and then underneath if the "ids" match it will list the results from "attachment".

Here is a screen shot of how it displays on the screen, I would like it the same as this. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52977510/example.jpg

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
<?php include '../../../connection_config.php'; 

$output = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id, project_name FROM projects_2016 
                    WHERE EXISTS 
                         (SELECT * FROM attachment 
                          WHERE projects_2016.id =  attachment_ABE_project_number) 
                          ORDER BY `id` DESC");

$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";
}

$filename = "2t.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;

?>
```

Revised code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="basic";
$password="redrobinX123";
$database = "basic_TEST_gauteng"; 


try {
$dbh = new PDO($host,$database,$username,$password);    
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// EXECUTE QUERY
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.*, a.*
        FROM projects_2016 p
        INNER JOIN attachment a
        ON p.id =  a.attachment_ABE_project_number
        ORDER BY `id` DESC";                          
$STH = $dbh->query($sql);    

// FETCH SQL QUERY RESUTS
$results = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// OPEN CSV IN WRITE MODE
$filename = '/path/CSV/Output.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

// WRITE TO CSV ITERATIVELY IN NESTED LOOP       
foreach($results as $outer) {
    fputcsv($fp, array('PNo', 'Project Name'));                   # HEADERS
    fputcsv($fp, array($outer['PNo'], $outer['Project Name']));   # ROWS

    foreach($results as $inner) {
        if ($inner['id'] == $outer['id']) {
            fputcsv($fp, array('File Name', 'File Type', 'File Size (KB)',     'View'));
            fputcsv($fp, array($inner['File Name'], $inner['File Type'], 
                               $inner['File Size'], $inner['View']));
        }
    }

}

// CLOSE CSV
fclose($fp);       

catch(PDOException $e) {  
echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
exit;
}

// CLOSE DB CONNECTION
$dbh = null;
```

?>

Comment: This format wouldn't really be a CSV, at least not as defined in RFC 4180.

Comment: @eggyal This format is fine, work fine for our system and needs

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following `PDO` example (as mysql_* is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and even [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) in PHP 7) that fetches database records and iteratively writes lines to csv with [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Your main issue is your SQL statement only retrieved projects_2016 data and not attachment data. As shown below, use a join query:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);    
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // EXECUTE QUERY
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.*, a.*
            FROM projects_2016 p
            INNER JOIN attachment a
            ON p.id =  a.attachment_ABE_project_number
            ORDER BY `id` DESC";                          
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    

    // FETCH SQL QUERY RESUTS
    $results = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // OPEN CSV IN WRITE MODE
    $filename = '/path/CSV/Output.csv';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

    // WRITE TO CSV ITERATIVELY IN NESTED LOOP       
    foreach($results as $outer) {
        fputcsv($fp, array('PNo', 'Project Name'));                   # HEADERS
        fputcsv($fp, array($outer['PNo'], $outer['Project Name']));   # ROWS

        foreach($results as $inner) {
            if ($inner['id'] == $outer['id']) {
                fputcsv($fp, array('File Name', 'File Type', 'File Size (KB)', 'View'));
                fputcsv($fp, array($inner['File Name'], $inner['File Type'], 
                                   $inner['File Size'], $inner['View']));
            }
        }   
    }
    // CLOSE CSV
    fclose($fp);       
}    
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

// CLOSE DB CONNECTION
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait, but i am getting a syntax error on line 47, by the Catch.

Comment: That worked however getting this error now: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous